# The `ApplicationCredential` instance is not valid. Details: `provider` can't be blank

Tags: node.js, passport.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to get Facebook login working with loopback using their [loopback-component-passport](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport) plugin.

I have configured app details in providers.json and now if I visit http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook I am redirected to facebook and can successfully login. However, when I get redirected back (to /auth/facebook/callback) I get the following error --

`ValidationError
422 The 'ApplicationCredential' instance is not valid. Details:`provider`can't be blank (value: undefined).`

I can't make sense of this error because the providers file is where the fb app and paths etc are configured and they are definitely working.

The plugin is poorly documented so I am out of ideas at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the cause for this error. I had initiated my loopback project as a blank project. However for `loopback-component-passport` to work it requires User, AccessToken, ACL models to be available. These are inbuilt in loopback and can be manually added to `model-config.json`. Or, you can initialize the project with user authentication and it should work.

This was one of many roadblocks that I ran into due to my lack of knowledge in the area and Loopback's poor documentation for the plugin. The Tutorial section in the docs and the example github project it links to are completely out of date.